# "lifespan" of .NET public static variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, static, public

I did a little *experiment*. On the **LoginButton_Click()** event from a **Login.aspx** button, I have a code that does something like:

```
MyClass.MyPublicStaticString = LoginNameTextBox.Text;
```

After logging in it goes to **Default.aspx** by FormsAuthentication. On Default.aspx, I have a code on **Page_Load()** like this:

```
Label1.Text = MyClass.MyPublicStaticString.ToString();
```

After waiting for a few minutes, Label1.Text becomes empty even **before** my login timeout expires.

What is happening here?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you are using Forms Authentication and need the user name why not just pull it from `User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: (1) Do you set the value anywhere else?  (2) be careful with public static string fields that show a username.  It's not thread safe so someone might get the wrong username.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Static fields are (unless `[ThreadStatic]`) one instance per app-domain, meaning: **all** requests share the **same** value. You need to be *exceptionally* careful using `static` in a web application. If in doubt: don't.

Re lifetime; the AppDomain; they won't be collected while assigned to the static field, and will expire if the App-Pool recycles in IIS.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use the Application State object. However it holds information that will persist for as long as the application is running. Session State, on the other hand has a lifetime that is tied to the visit by the current user, plus a default of 20 minutes thereafter to verify the s/he is not just snacking temporarily and using a slow network. Besides, ApplicationState is visible / accessible to all user contexts; while Session is visible and accessible only in the context of the current user. On the third hand, Postbacks are limited in context to the context of the last page sent from the Server, because a postback happens when the Browser returns the Page to the Server including the result(s) of the user action(s). The lifecyle of the Page is different from that of the Session, and that of the ApplicationState, and should not be confused, any one with any other.

Answer (score 3):

I've never worked with ASP.NET, but I can tell you that static variables do not expire, or anything like that.

My best is that this has to do with another request resetting the variable somehow, or possibly even re-launching the whole application, creating a brand new memory space, and obviously without the previous static value.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for this kind of thing.
If you don't, two users logging in within short period of time **will both get last user's name** because it was stored last in `MyPublicStaticString`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your application's Page class is not longer in memory at your webserver thats why your static variable disappers but your authentication cookie is still valid as your asp.net forms authentication timeout may not be expired yet.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use the ASP.NET [Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28VS.85%29.aspx) object instead as in ASP.NET this will also maintain state across multiple Postbacks / Sessions?